# Label node in CircuiTikz

Tags: nodes, circuitikz

It is easy to set a label to a component, but is it possible to place a label on a single node?

For example, what I would be after, circled in red here:

[image: example]

Comment: Please, add a complete document clearly illustrating your inetnt (i.e., a simple example of a circuit showing the "node" you want to label).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina sorry, done.

Comment: Look at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/circuitikz/ The example is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a standard TikZ node and its `label` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw 
  (0,0) 
    node[label={[font=\footnotesize]above:Node}] {}
  to[R,*-*] (2,0) 
    node[label={[font=\footnotesize]-30:$1$},label={[font=\footnotesize]150:$2$}] {}
  to[R,*-*] (4,0) 
    node[label={[font=\footnotesize]above:$3$}] {}
;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]